# React native / native base : how to include a skeleton (header / footer) in all screens?

Tags: react-native, native-base

What would be a good way to include header / footer or other components in all screens of a react native application that uses native-base ?

Mostly to avoid code duplication and make it easier to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Composition concept.
https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Make a skeleton class/function ( containing header, footer or other components ) and have it render `this.props.children` in the section where you want the content to be.

```
export class Skeleton {
 ...

 render(){

  return (
    <Container>
     <Header />

     {this.props.children}

    </Container>
  );
 }
}
```

Then import it & use

```
class NewScreen {
     ...

     render(){

      return (
       <Skeleton> 
        <View>...</View>
       </Skeleton>
      );
     }
}
```